# How to create method interface with variable parameters / different method signatures?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, methods

I'm trying to create an interface to a common class, but the implementation classes can have different parameters.

e.g.

```
public interface IViewModel
{
    //...
    void ResetReferences(); 
}

// and then, in my class implementations, something like this:
public class LocationViewModel : IViewModel
{
    public void ResetReferences(List<StateProvinces> stateProvinces) //...
}

public class ProductViewModel : IViewModel
{
    public void ResetReferences(List<Color> colors, List<Size> sizes) //...
}
```

So notice that I want to standardize on the `ResetReferences` naming convention. I'm pretty sure I can't do this, but is there a design pattern that could work? e.g. in my interface, something like below?

```
// variable parameters
void ResetReferences(params object[] list);
```

But then how do I make I do type checking or having it call the actual method signature that I want, etc?

Maybe an interface is the wrong thing to use? Maybe just a base class and some coding conventions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Replace your args lists with objects that implement a related interface:

```
public interface IViewModel
{
    //...
    void ResetReferences(IResetValues vals); 
}
```

I should add that, IMO, `ResetReferences()` should not take an argument... it should reset to some default value that would be specific to the individual type(s) that implement your interface..."Reset" being the word that means, to me, "restore to initial state"...adding args implies that you can control that.

Comment: I like your approach, thank you. BTW, I've renamed the method to "SetReferences" :)

Comment: @Raymond: If you like this answer upvote it and give JeffSahol 10 more reputation points. People appreciate a "thank you" comment, but in the great hunt for reputation a comment won't help.

Answer (score 19):

The purpose of an interface is to have client code know about the interface and be oblivious of the implementation. If your implementations require special treatment when called, the client code need to know what implementation it is calling and then the whole purpose of the interface is lost.

Unless I misunderstand totally what you're trying to accomplish, you're down the wrong road.

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct. I'm putting the logic in the wrong place. (This is an MVC application, so I've put the ResetReferences in the Controller class instead of the ViewModel class now).

Comment: That's absolutely right. Having hidden away functionality in implementing class takes away a lot of value from `interface` since the `interface` doesn't completely define what the implementing classes are going to do.

Answer (score 18):

If the parameters can be different, then it isn't really a common interface. Put it this way: does the *caller* need to know the *implementation* class? If so, you've lost the loose coupling benefits of interfaces.

One option is to encapsulate the parameters into another type, and make the class generic on that type. For example:

```
public interface IViewModel<T>
{
    void ResetReferences(T data);
}
```

Then you'd encapsulate the `List<Color> colors, List<Size> sizes` into one type, and possibly put `List<StateProvinces> stateProvinces` in another.

It's somewhat awkward though...

Comment: *"It's somewhat awkward though..."* What is the most desirable way to approach this problem?

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy: Ideally "don't get yourself in this situation". I've given the best answer I could given the limited information - it's very context-sensitive.

Comment: I don't think you can do anything generic in the implementation of `ResetReferences(T data)`, `T` has no common interface to act on.

Comment: @zoujyjs: But the implementation doesn't have to be generic - it could be specific to one type. It's not the method that's generic - it's the interface. So someone could implement `IViewModel<Foo>` and they only need to know what to do with Foo.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement the interface method, but you can still do what you want

```
public class LocationViewModel : IViewModel
{
    public void ResetReferences(List<StateProvinces> stateProvinces) // ...

    void IViewModel.ResetReferences() // ...
}
```

Comment: That is no good solution, because it violates the interface segregation principle (ISP) of the SOLID principle: a class must not have to implement any interface element that is not required by the particular class!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have both methods in the interface (and have the one not correct for an instance throw a non-supported exception), or have the interface inherit from two other interfaces to the same effect.

An interface definition is the entire signature.

It may also be possible to pass an object as a parameter (perhaps derived from a ParameterProvider base class) so that the object encapsulates the dynamic nature and still allows the interface to be static.  But that that point you're basically working around the type system anyway.