# Defining an interface for external system integration

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, interface, integration

I want to integrate my application with X number of external systems. The integration with each external system will have same kind of actions but will be handled in a separate classes.

Hence the aim to define an interface that will make sure all integration classes conform to certain actions. e.g.

```
public interface IOrderIntegration
{
   //I want to define the ImportOrder action here, so that all future integrations conform
}
```

However each external system has its own closed SDK (cannot be edited) that needs to be referenced. e.g

```
public class EbayOrderIntegration : IOrderIntegration
{
    void ImportOrder(Ebay.SDK.Order order)
    {
        //Logic to import Ebay's order
    }
}


public class AmazonOrderIntegration : IOrderIntegration
{
    void ImportOrder(Amazon.SDK.Order order)
    {
        //Logic to import Amazon's order
    }
}
```

Is there a way to still use an interface in this case to ensure all integrations perform a certain action? Or perhaps another pattern ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create method interface with variable parameters / different method signatures?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114519/how-to-create-method-interface-with-variable-parameters-different-method-signa)

Comment: You have interface for method name, now you need another for method parameters (or just use `object` and cast).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where generics come intp play:

```
public interface IOrderIntegration<T>
{
   void ImportOrder(T order);
}

public class EbayOrderIntegration : IOrderIntegration<Ebay.SDK.Order order> 
{ 
    void ImportOrder(Ebay.SDK.Order order order)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way than HimBromBeere's answer (great answer by the way !). Note that this can only work if you can abstract at the order level:

```
public class OrderIntegration
{
    public void ImportOrder(IOrder order)
    {
        // Only possible if you can abstract all the logic into IOrder
    }
}

public interface IOrder
{
     // Abstract here the order logic
}

public class EbayOrder : IOrder
{
    public EbayOrder(Ebay.SDK.Order order)
    { .. }
}

public class AmazonOrder : IOrder
{
    public AmazonOrder(Amazon.SDK.Order order)
    { .. }
}
```

The choice between HimBromBeere's anwser and mine will depend on where you want to (and can!) abstract your different providers and how you want to use your API.

Comment: Be aware that with this approach you could also write `new AmazonOrder(new Ebay.SDK.Order())`.

Comment: Oops, I failed my copy/paste ^^. Fixed!